# Associativity of pullbacks

Tags: category-theory, pullback

Consider two arrows in a category: $k:A\longrightarrow D$ and $h:B\longrightarrow D$ and take their pullback
$$\begin{array}
AA\times_DB & \stackrel{k'}{\longrightarrow} & B \\
\downarrow{h'} & & \downarrow{h} \\
A & \stackrel{k}{\longrightarrow} & D  
\end{array}
$$
Then consider two other arrows: $g:B\longrightarrow E$ and $f:C\longrightarrow E$ and take the following pullback
$$\begin{array}
((A\times_DB)\times_EC & \stackrel{(gk')'}{\longrightarrow} & C \\
\downarrow{f'} & & \downarrow{f} \\
A\times_DB & \stackrel{gk'}{\longrightarrow} & E  
\end{array}
$$
Now, using the same arrows, consider first the following pullback
$$\begin{array}
BB\times_EC & \stackrel{g''}{\longrightarrow} & C \\
\downarrow{f''} & & \downarrow{f} \\
B & \stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow} & E  
\end{array}
$$
and then the following
$$\begin{array}
AA\times_D(B\times_EC) & \stackrel{k''}{\longrightarrow} & B\times_EC \\
\downarrow{(hf'')''} & & \downarrow{hf''} \\
A & \stackrel{k}{\longrightarrow} & D  
\end{array}
$$
What I want is an isomorphism
$$(A\times_DB)\times_EC\simeq A\times_D(B\times_EC)$$
My guess is that the two sides of that relation are two pullbacks of the same object, hence isomorphic, but I can't prove it. More precisely, I think we can define a pullback of three (or more) objects, then show that the two sides of that relation are both "realizations" of the ternary pullback of $A,B$ and $C$, hence isomorphic.

This is what I call the associativity property of pullbacks and it is my first question. Looking for references, I found on Borceux categorical algebra handbook vol 1, the following: the associativity of pullbacks is defined as the following property (which I can understand and prove): consider a commutative diagram
$$\begin{array}
AA & \stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} & B & \stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow} & C\\
\downarrow{h} & & \downarrow{k}& & \downarrow{l} \\
D & \stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow} & E  & \stackrel{q}{\longrightarrow} & F
\end{array}
$$
Then the following facts hold true:

1) if both squares are pullbacks then the outer rectangle is a pullback

2) if the right square and the outer rectangle are pullbacks, then the left square is a pullback

So my second question is: why this property is called associativity of pullbacks? Is there a relation between this notion and the one I described above?

Comment: Regarding your first question: (a) just show that in either case you have constructed the limit of the diagram $A\to D\leftarrow B \to E \leftarrow C$ (in fact you only need to show this once, since the situation is symmetric). (b) using the Yoneda embedding it is sufficient to prove this in the category of sets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are calling associativity and what they are calling are associativity are related as follows.
Consider the diagram
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
R @>{r_2}>> B\times_E C @>{q_2}>> C\\
@V{r_1}VV @VV{q_1}V @VV{f}V\\
A\times_D B @>{p_2}>> B @>{g}>> E\\
@V{p_1}VV @VV{h}V \\
A @>>{k}> D
\end{CD}$$
where each of the squares are pullbacks. Using 1 of from Borceux's categorical algebra horizontally and vertically we see that 
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
R @>{q_2r_2}>> C\\
@V{r_1}VV  @VV{f}V\\
A\times_D B @>>{gp_2}> E
\end{CD}$$
and
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
R @>{r_2}>> B\times_E C \\
@V{p_1r_1}VV @VV{hq_1}V\\
A @>>{k}> D
\end{CD}$$
are pullbacks. The desired isomorphism is then obtained as the composite of the (obvious) isomorphisms $(A\times_D B)\times_E C \to R$ and $R \to A\times_D(B\times_E C)$.