# Associativity of pushouts

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

They know some reference where it is shown the pushout associative property?

$$(B\underset{A}{\sqcup}C)\underset{D}{\sqcup}E \simeq B\underset{A}{\sqcup}(C\underset{D}{\sqcup}E)$$

Comment: It's probably easier to find results for the associativity of pullbacks which is formally dual to the associativity of pushouts. It's not hard to prove yourself though.

Comment: Dualize [this argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2046276/associativity-of-pullbacks)